# ReactJS Push Redirect After Dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I want to push to /auth/login after logout button in sidebar clicked
But it still stay on /dasboard page
I'm pretty sure the props has been passed to the action and the logout is successfull but the push isn't working

Console.log:

```
{
    "length": 50,
    "action": "PUSH",
    "location": {
        "pathname": "/dashboard",
        "search": "",
        "hash": "",
        "key": "lz9l8p"
    }
}
```

Sidebar Component:

```
<button className="dropdown-item preview-item" onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(logoutUserAction(this.props.history))}>
Logout
</button>

export default connect()(withRouter(Sidebar));
```

Dispatch Action:

```
export const logoutUserAction = history => dispatch => {
  console.log(history)
  //! Loading
  dispatchLoading(dispatch, LOGOUT_USER_ACTION);

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Success Logout...');
      window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
      AlertInfo('Success...', 'Successfully Logout...', 'success');
      history.push('/auth/login');
      dispatchSuccess(dispatch, LOGOUT_USER_ACTION, 'Success Logout!!!');
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Failed Logout...');
      window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
      AlertInfo('Oops...', 'Something Went Wrong...', 'error');
      history.push('/auth/login');
      dispatchError(dispatch, LOGOUT_USER_ACTION, 'Failed Logout!!!');
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you share your `Router` component and routes in your question? By any chance are you using more than one router? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you see alerts from `AlertInfo`? (to be sure that `history.push` is called) If than check also log for errors from `history`. Try to listen the `hashchange` event on `window` and log url changes.

Comment: Along with that, you might want to also use the error in the catch block. A message "Oops, ***something*** went wrong ‍♂️" alone isn't helpful at all, but if any part of the error message was included then now you'll have something to work with.